# How can I change from programming view to interface builder from halfway?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4, interface-builder

From halfway I want to change programming view to xib file. How can I do this?

First I choose programming view because number of view change dynamic and programming it is easy. But this view becomes more complex in step by step. I feel difficult this control programming way. And I'm confused more because this is "view", not "view controller".

Many sample code contain:

fooViewController.m, fooViewController.h, fooViewController.xib

I understand this.

In my case (pseudocode):

```
[rect CGRect];
[addSubview rect];
[button1 UIButton];
[addSubview button1];
[button2 UIButton];
[addSubview button2];
[image UIImage];
[addSubview UIImage];
[label1 UILabel];
...
```

I want change this block to xib. (block is not mean objective-c's "block").

My environment:
Xcode3.2.6, iOS4.3, For iPhone app

Answer (score 0):

I dont know of any way to go from code to XIB. You are probably going to have to bite the bullet and just sit down and do it - if may not take that much time. But IB doesn't export all possible interfaces of all view's, so there may still be stuff you need to do programmatically in your viewDidLoad function.

Sounds like you are starting out - get just about any book now in iOS programming (and there have to be 10-20 out there at this point) and go through the first few chapters and they will walk you through using IB.